# Data isn't inserted in database

Tags: c#, database-connection, sql-server-ce

Data isn't inserted into database from my C# app, but there's no error or exception found. But I can read the data from database using select statement and data reader.

```
  private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string conString = Properties.Settings.Default.dbConnectionString;

        // Open the connection using the connection string.
        SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(conString);
        con.Open();

        // Insert into the SqlCe table. ExecuteNonQuery is best for inserts.

        SqlCeCommand com = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO test VALUES('num')", con);

        com.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        // com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@num", "num");
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("ok");

    }
```

After pressing the button the message box shows. But data is not inserted.

Connection string:

```
Data Source=d:\manu\smalldb\smalldb\db.sdf
```

Comment: are you certain you're looking in the right database?

Comment: btw, you should close your connection.

Comment: Can you trace the insert query with a SQL Profiler?

Comment: Always: `using (SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(conString)) { ... }`. Disposes and closes the connection.

Comment: Show the part with the parameter too. Did you use `Parameters.Add()` ?

Comment: And verify that `com.ExecuteNonQuery();` returns the value `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have to do some commit to validate the transaction

Like [HERE](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Forums/Thread/43026/)

OR

Maybe the problem is in the place where the insertion is done and the place you look after.

Look [HERE](http://dean-o.blogspot.be/2010/03/mind-your-copy-to-output-directory.html) if it is the case. this article speaks about the "Copy to Output Directory" settings. It can be your problem!

Comment: should be a comment. The link you have given does not appear to answer this question....

Comment: +1 for the output directory, sometimes a copy of the db is done into the debug Folder and data are inserted there.

Comment: The OP lists a fixed connectionstring, the Output dire is not involved.

Comment: connectionstring was an edit after the answer and it seems to be the problem in fact if we look at the OP accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

Your application is working on copy of database file.

To ensure that is the source of problem - take a look into bin/Debug directory of your project. There should be a database file with all changes and file should have fresh timestamp in "date modified".

To change this behavior you have to change **"Copy to Output Directory" property** of database file in your project. If you want to work on database, not on copy - **set it to "Do not copy"**.

For more information please read this:

1. [Local Data Overview (at MSDN Library)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233817%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) IMPORTANT
2. [How to: Manage Local Data Files in Your Project (at MSDN Library)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246989%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
3. [VB.NET only seems to update the debug database, how do I have it make changes to the live one? (as MSDN Social)](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vbgeneral/thread/25a093d2-8520-4727-8c6b-f5c3aefb3c2b) (its about VB not C#, but it doesnt matter).

Comment: That only happens with `|DataDirectory|` in the connectionstring.

Answer (score 0):

```
int count = cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();    
if (count > 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show(" details Entered Successfully");
    clear();
}
else
    MessageBox.Show("Details Not Entered");

con.Close();
```